# how to set checkmark invisible

Tags: java, android

I want to hide check mark in the check box button in class code not xml file .
cuz i'm using two background if checked true set background .. if false set background "checkbox.png"

public class ListActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);


    AbsoluteLayout ff = (AbsoluteLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.AbsoluteLayout1);

    ScrollView myScrollView =  (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);
    TableLayout tl =(TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.h103);
    TableRow tr = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.TableRow18);
    CheckBox cb =  (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.CheckBox18);
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView34);





//  ScrollView myScrollView1 = new  ScrollView(this);
    TableLayout tl1 =new TableLayout(this);
    TableRow tr1 = new  TableRow(this);
    final CheckBox buttonView = new CheckBox(this) ;
    TextView tv1 = new  TextView(this);

    /*myScrollView.getLayoutParams();
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams iv_params_b = myScrollView1.getLayoutParams();
    myScrollView1.setLayoutParams(iv_params_b);*/


    //buttonView.setVisibility(1);
    buttonView.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.checkbox));
    //buttonView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    buttonView.setFocusable(false);

    buttonView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            if(((CheckBox) v).isChecked())
            {           

                //buttonView.setChecked(false);
                buttonView.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.star));

            }else
            {
                //buttonView.setChecked(true);
                buttonView.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.checkbox));

            } 

        }
    });


     /* if(isChecked)
        {               
            buttonView.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.star));
        }else
        {
            buttonView.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.checkbox));
        }   */











    ViewGroup.LayoutParams iv_params_b = tl.getLayoutParams();
    tl1.setLayoutParams(iv_params_b);


    ViewGroup.LayoutParams iv_params_b1 = tr.getLayoutParams();
    tr1.setLayoutParams(iv_params_b1);


    ViewGroup.LayoutParams iv_params_b2 = cb.getLayoutParams();
    buttonView.setLayoutParams(iv_params_b2);


    ViewGroup.LayoutParams iv_params_b3 = tv.getLayoutParams();
    tv1.setLayoutParams(iv_params_b3);

    tl.addView(tr1);
    tr1.addView(buttonView);

  }
   }
```

Comment: http://learningnerd.wordpress.com/2006/09/06/english-grammar-types-of-phrases/ and http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/grammar/overview.html . Couldn't understand what you want and what you have exactly. Sorry :-(

Comment: when i clicked in check box button there is blue check mark . i want to hide this check mark only cuz i'm using different background

Comment: See this link (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#INVISIBLE) and if you have problems implementing it, get back here and explain.

Comment: not effective it's hide all by check box ,, i think this method will work "abstract boolean  isCheckable()
Return whether the item can currently display a check mark."

Answer (score 0):

You probably should be using the framework's constants, like [View.Gone](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#GONE)

Comment: Since he's trying to set the background of the View, it still needs to be there.

Comment: i have put : buttonView.setVisibility(2); but not effective ,, i want to hide internal checkMark .

Comment: 2 problems: your problem's description isn't all that clear. You should really be using the named constants (View.GONE, View.INVISIBLE) for clarity's sake.

Comment: i have used View.GONE but it's hide all my check-box i want only hide check-mark that's appearing inside check-box

Answer (score 0):

save this as a xml in drawable folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item
     android:state_checked="true" android:state_focused="true"
  android:drawable="@drawable/checked"/>
  <item
    android:state_checked="false" android:state_focused="false" 
     android:drawable="@drawable/notchecked" 
     />
</selector>
```

and set this as your checkbox `andriod:button="@drawable/yourxmlfile.`

The you dont need to change the image programmatically.

Hope this will help you.

**checkbox.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)** this is the answer for which you have asked.

**EDIT**

```
final CheckBox checkBox1=new CheckBox(MainActivity.this);

checkBox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton paramCompoundButton,
            boolean paramBoolean) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (paramBoolean) {

            checkBox1.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            //here you can change 
        }
        else
        {
            checkBox1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        }
    }
});
```

check out the code...

Comment: no i want to use it programmatically cuz i will using for loop .

Comment: for that just get the status alone ... if(checkbox.ischecked()){ //do your stuff.. }

Comment: View.INVISIBLE it will hide all my Check box button :(  i want only hide check-mark inside my check-button

Comment: you can change the status of your check box like below.  checkBox1.setChecked(true);

Comment: you have done the code in your click listener.. it will change the sate of your checkbox if you click it . (check or unchceck )

Comment: the check button it works , but when i clicked on it .. there is small blue "check mark " appearing , i want to hide this check mark .

Comment: i did not using xml for this button ,, i want it programmatically ,,

Comment: you have created the checkbox at runtime ?

Comment: hi for checkbox you should not use clicklistener... have to use setOnCheckedChangeListener

Comment: hi your checkbox backgroud will get dynamically change or static images ?

Comment: i have two check background images one of check state and another of unchecked state .. one of them are here : img507.imageshack.us/img507/8172/starlu.png